# Php session retrieve

Tags: php, session

Basically i want that the php script relocate the user to a different location based on input. This input is recieved by another page.

This is the script with modification by help. unfortunately it doesnt respond

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    @session_start();

    $name = $_SESSION['username'];

    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
            if (preg_match("/^A/", $_SESSION['username'], $match)) {
          header('Location: page.php');
          } elseif (preg_match("/^B/", $_SESSION['username'], $match)) {
          header('Location: page1.php');
          }
       else {
          header('Location: page2.php');
    }
    ?>

The other (html) code.

    <?php
    session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['username'];
           ?>

        <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
        <html>
        <body>  

        <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
        <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
        <form method="post" action="test.php">  
          Name: <input type="text" name="username">
          <span class="error">*</span>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
        </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Why are you suppressing `session_start()`? And the code you're showing here has nothing to do with the session.

Comment: this question is too unclear and where `$line` is defined and how.

Comment: Not familair with the supressing session start. Where do i do this and why is that?

Comment: I took the $line out, because i want the value to come from another page.

Comment: @th.cook Don't suspress function as they show usefull error information. It will help you find errors and debug your code. There is no need for suspressing the `session_start` function.

Comment: This is the code with $line in it: <?php
   $line = "A";
   
   if (preg_match("/^A/", $line, $match)) {
      echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=test.php\">";
      } elseif (preg_match("/^B/", $line, $match)) {
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=test1.php\">";
      }
   else {
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=test2.php\">";
}
?>

Comment: @C0dekid if i'm correct. I have to remove the session_start in the php script to stop the suppressing

Comment: The session is not a magic tool to do stuff automatically for you. To use the session you need to actually store things in the `$_SESSION` array in one page and use them in another page.

Comment: @th.cook only start the session if you are going to use sessions. Otherwise it is unnecessary to have it in your code.

Comment: @apokryfos so for instance in the html page i put the code $_SESSION["user"] = "user"; to store the session that can be use by the other script?

Comment: @th.cook Yes.That would be the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are having problem at, you want to redirect something or someone to another page and also use session..
 1. First you need to start the output buffering for redirection to be possible as the header get sent first to server, try searching it first and use `ob_start();` at the start of your php page. 
 2. Then use `session_start();` to start session and you can now be able to store data in a variable like this `$user = $_SESSION['username'];` and relocate or redirect using header  `if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('Location: admin.php');
}` and retrieve the data to other page or even transfer it to a variable or do whatever you want in another page using the same session from another page. `$othervariable = $_SESSION['username'];`

Comment: my apologies for the late reply. I will try to apply your suggestion and come back to you with the outcome. This may take a couple hours due circumstances. Thanks in advance

Comment: unfortunately the code doesnot work. i tried to apply your suggestion in my code. But each time with no responds of the php script. this is how i implemented the code:  <?php
ob_start();
@session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['username'];

if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        if (preg_match("/^4/", $_SESSION['username'], $match)) {
      header('Location: MCsecure.php');
      } elseif (preg_match("/^5/", $_SESSION['username'], $match)) {
      header('Location: Vsecure.php');
      }
   else {
      header('Location: index.php');
}
?>

Comment: Found errors in your code above like you forgot to close your if statement (closing)bracket.. try my edit, it is working now.. ^_^

Comment: be sure to post to the right php file for redirection, I was expecting that test.php in your form action attribute is this page it self..